# JSONDecodeError at /send-notif/ Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) while sending notification using firebase in django

Tags: django, firebase

JSONDecodeError at /send-notif/
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

code
`def send_notification(registration_ids , message_title , message_desc):
fcm_api = ""
url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"

```
headers = {
"Content-Type":"application/json",
"Authorization": 'key='+fcm_api
}

payload = {
    "registration_ids" :['e1aLmMZPeegz36PP3KUw0t:APA91bGjoJBwraENbW9PHsE5IUVIh_lLhnPI99qqr_VewvRFLjbJbu_vcSfT0dk4Tu4CGbcvUfR-x8INAkqovEDuJB4OdQma2NrEPsGufjtrsizYskD_ANCpKjT5wltIAfzJkbjY0YAV'],
    "priority" : "high",
    "notification" : {
        "body" : "message desc",
        "title" : "message_title",
        "image" : "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/m5WUPHRgdOA/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEXCOADEI4CSFryq4qpAwkIARUAAIhCGAE=&rs=AOn4CLDwz-yjKEdwxvKjwMANGk5BedCOXQ",
        "icon": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AKedOLSMvoy4DeAVkMSAuiuaBdIGKC7a5Ib75bKzKO3jHg=s900-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
        
    }
}

result = requests.post(url,  data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers )
print(result.json())`
```

not able to send notifications to my user

Comment: what do you get with `print((result.status_code, result.content))` *before* the `print(result.json())`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior for request's .json method.
From the docs:
https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content

> In case the JSON decoding fails, r.json() raises an exception. For
> example, if the response gets a 204 (No Content), or if the response
> contains invalid JSON, attempting r.json() raises
> requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError

Make sure the request is successful by inspecting result.status_code and make sure response.content returns a json document.